# Android check if 2 records exist using database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a function that works correctly when I check for the userName. When I check password it is always false.

```
public boolean checkIfUser(String userName, String password){

        //validate user if the user exists return true.
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String query ="select * from user_table where user_name = "+"\""+userName+"\"";
        //String query ="select * from user_table where password = "+"\""+password+"\"";

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
        if(cursor.getCount() <=0){
            return  false;
        }
        return true;

    }
```

To check password I changed the String to

```
   String query ="select * from user_table where password = "+"\""+ password +"\"";
```

Any ideas what can be causing this error?

Comment: can you show your create table query?

Comment: try to trim your password field like password.trim()

Comment: I tried password.trim() did not work.

Comment: @RanjithKumar I did    
    public static final String COL1_USER_NAME = "user_name";
    public static final String COL2_PASSWORD = "password";

Comment: I want to know your create table query not variable declaration

Comment: db.execSQL("create table " + Table_NAME+"(user_name TEXT,password TEXT,email TEXT,first_name TEXT,last_name TEXT)");

Comment: query seems right. Problem may be inserting with spaces. trim before inserting

Answer (score 0):

Try using

`String query ="select * from user_table where user_name = "'"+userName+"'";
String query ="select * from user_table where password = "'"+password+"'";`

This may help

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM " + Table_NAME + " WHERE (" + COL2_PASSWORD + " = \'" + password + "\')";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try validating your login information like this:

```
String[] selectionArg = new String[]{userName, password};
String query ="select * from user_table where user_name = ? and password = ?";
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,selectionArg);
 if(cursor.getCount() <=0){
    return  false;
}
return true;
```